# Debugging Silverlight crash

Tags: silverlight, debugging

I am trying to debug an IE 8 crash caused by a Silverlight application. I managed to find some articles on how to do a memory dump when a process crashes. I loaded the dump in windbg and ran !analyze -v. Below is the result. I am stuck at what further steps I can take to figure out what module or library that is running in Silverlight is causing the crash. So all I have right now is the crash in IE is caused by an Access violation (attempt to execute non-executable address) and from what is in the stack trace that some animation is running in Silverlight.

Any tips or articles that would help me debug this will be appreciated.

```
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
```

The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(1864.1560): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=1b11fc58 edx=5c6f007d esi=00000000 edi=193b8e08
eip=00000000 esp=0f61f750 ebp=0f61f76c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
00000000 ??              ???

FAULTING_IP: 
+56b3952f04ebde68
748bc9f1 654c            dec     esp

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 748bc9f1
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000008
   Parameter[1]: 00000000
Attempt to execute non-executable address 00000000

PROCESS_NAME:  iexplore.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000008

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000000

WRITE_ADDRESS:  00000000

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
agcore!CFrameworkElement::SetValue+1d7
5c704fa8 84c0            test    al,al

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
+56b3952f04ebde68
748bc9f1 654c            dec     esp

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

FAULTING_THREAD:  00001560

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NULL

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NULL

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NULL

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 5c704fa8 to 00000000

STACK_TEXT:
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
0f61f74c 5c704fa8 1b17a134 193b8e08 0e690e14 0x0
0f61f76c 5c712360 0e690e14 1b17a134 0e690e14 agcore!CFrameworkElement::SetValue+0x1d7
0f61f788 5c7123a8 0e690e14 1b17a134 0e690e14 agcore!CShape::SetValue+0x72
0f61f7a0 5c70a6ff 0e690e14 1b17a134 00000000 agcore!CEllipse::SetValue+0x3b
0f61f7d0 5c752c2b 1b17a090 193b8e08 00000000 agcore!CAnimation::DoSetValue+0x50
0f61f810 5c7a7fb1 0f61f884 0f61f868 1b17a090 agcore!CAnimation::UpdateAnimationUsingKeyFrames+0x3b5
0f61f82c 5c707146 00000000 00000000 00000000 agcore!CAnimation::UpdateAnimation+0x184
0f61f87c 5c7071e5 3e4c8000 0f61f8cc 00000000 agcore!CTimeline::ComputeState+0x13a
0f61f89c 5c706d49 193f82b0 0f61f8cc 0f61f8d4 agcore!CTimelineGroup::ComputeState+0x8c
0f61f8ac 5c7069c7 3e4c8000 0f61f8cc 0b111f60 agcore!CStoryboard::ComputeState+0x48
0f61f8d4 5c706a29 0e6a0ca0 00000000 0e490070 agcore!CTimeManager::Tick+0x79
0f61f8e8 5c78f960 0b0e6d68 0f61f990 00000000 agcore!CCoreServices::Tick+0x21
0f61f940 5c706ac2 0b111f60 0e42ca08 ffffffff agcore!CCoreServices::Draw+0x140
0f61f964 67ac141c 0af99b90 00000000 0f61f990 agcore!CCoreServices::Draw+0x2d
0f61f9b4 67a933c2 0f61f9c8 00000000 00000000 npctrl!CXcpBrowserHost::OnTick+0x1b1
0f61f9e0 67a927c6 0064069c 00000402 00000000 npctrl!CXcpDispatcher::Tick+0xf3
0f61fa08 67a92709 0064069c 00000402 00000000 npctrl!CXcpDispatcher::OnReentrancyProtectedWindowMessage+0xcd
0f61fa28 764b6238 0064069c 00000402 00000000 npctrl!CXcpDispatcher::WindowProc+0xb8
0f61fa54 764b68ea 67a9269d 0064069c 00000402 user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
0f61facc 764b7d31 00000000 67a9269d 0064069c user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x109
0f61fb2c 764b7dfa 67a9269d 00000000 0f61fbb4 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x3bc
0f61fb3c 6fe504a6 0f61fb54 00000000 0ab11908 user32!DispatchMessageW+0xf
0f61fbb4 6fe60446 0af956a0 00000000 0b18a338 ieframe!CTabWindow::_TabWindowThreadProc+0x452
0f61fc6c 769d49bd 0ab11908 00000000 0f61fc88 ieframe!LCIETab_ThreadProc+0x2c1
0f61fc7c 76e53677 0b18a338 0f61fcc8 77829d72 iertutil!CIsoScope::RegisterThread+0xab
0f61fc88 77829d72 0b18a338 7dbc895d 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0f61fcc8 77829d45 769d49af 0b18a338 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0f61fce0 00000000 769d49af 0b18a338 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  agcore!CFrameworkElement::SetValue+1d7

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: agcore

IMAGE_NAME:  agcore.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a67e422

STACK_COMMAND:  ~44s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NULL_c0000005_agcore.dll!CFrameworkElement::SetValue

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_NULL_BAD_IP_agcore!CFrameworkElement::SetValue+1d7

Answer (score 0):

This morning one of the third-party libraries that we were using in Silverlight was updated and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Hi, could you share the name/version of the 3rd party library causing this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to identify the cause you would have to get the memory dump and look for call-stack. Here are couple of links to identify the cause [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/02/08/net-debugging-demos-lab-2-crash.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/08/21/debugging-silverlight-applications-with-windbg-and-sos-dll.aspx)

Here is existing answer [Is anyone else experiencing weird debug + crash behavior with Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557407/is-anyone-else-experiencing-weird-debug-crash-behavior-with-silverlight/2576150#2576150)