# Is anyone else experiencing weird debug + crash behavior with Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, browser, silverlight-3.0, debugging, crash

I have noticed that after awhile of debug/tweakcode/debug etc that eventually Silverlight starts to crash all of my browsers (i.e. doesn't matter which i fire, they all just crash). If i then go to a site that has Silverlight, it works fine? so it has something to do with debugger + Silverlight not getting along?

I then reboot and the problem goes away?  Is anyone else experiencing this kind of weird behaviour?

I have noticed though that if i put breakpoints on the code they all seem to halt, in that it appears that it can instantiate the said .xap etc ok, but just can't seem to render it to screen without a crash?

(There's nothing in the log files and i've tried to attach a seperate VS2008 instance to both IE, Devenv and Blend etc trying to see if i can catch what's causing this to occur?)

Comment: If you create an applciation with just a single Grid, will it crash? If so, try to reinstall the silverlight plug-in and development tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways to figure out cause of this issue

One is using XPERF - If you are using Windows VISTA [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/seema/archive/2008/10/08/xperf-a-cpu-sampler-for-silverlight.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ntdebugging/archive/2008/04/03/windows-performance-toolkit-xperf.aspx)

or using Windbg by getting a memory dump and here is a [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/08/21/debugging-silverlight-applications-with-windbg-and-sos-dll.aspx) from Tess

Comment: None of the above worked. I think it had something to do with VS2010 RC and VS2008 being side by side. I uninstalled VS2010 and it essentially resolved the issue.